# text from EdittextPreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, edittextpreference

My `EditTextPreference` is this:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:title="Name"
    android:summary="namepreferences"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:dialogTitle="name"
    />
```

in my PreferencesActivity:

```
namePref = (EditTextPreference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference("namepreferences");
```

well so far no problem.. now, i have a service with a notification. My goal is pass the namePref value in the Title of the notification.. I wrote this in the service:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultPreferences(this);
String name;

@Override 
  public void onCreate() {
    name = sp.getText("namepreferences", "NA");

  }
```

and i insert `name` in the title of notification but the app crashes sayng that name is null.. I can't solve..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
SharedPreferences sp;
String name;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    name = sp.getText("namepreferences", "NA");
}
```

Comment: It crashes again.. same result :(, sorry i didn't see the edit.. i try

Comment: Yeah it works!! Thanks.. the problem was the SharedPreferences declaration. thank you